# Postgres querying rolling SUM for every day according to a result of generate_serial

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I have a table and I want to make a query which shows the inventory of a product on each day of a period, not only the date when inventory movement was done.

My solution is:

`SELECT gs::date, COALESCE(moves,0), btb_goods 
FROM generate_series('2017-10-01','2017-11-30',INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS gs 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(btb_menny),0) as moves, btb_goods, btb_date FROM mytable GROUP BY btb_goods, btb_date) AS mozg 
ON (date(mozg.btb_date) = gs) ORDER BY 1 ASC;`

It works. The result is:

```
 2017-11-05 |        0 |         |     
 2017-11-06 |        0 |         |     
 2017-11-07 |        0 |         |     
 2017-11-08 |     54.1 |   sugar |  
 2017-11-09 |        0 |         |    
 2017-11-10 |        0 |         |    
 2017-11-11 |        0 |
```

A want the result is rolling over from the date of inventory occurence, like this:

```
 2017-11-05 |        0 |         |     
 2017-11-06 |        0 |         |     
 2017-11-07 |        0 |         |     
 2017-11-08 |     54.1 |   sugar |  
 2017-11-09 |     54.1 |   sugar |    
 2017-11-10 |     54.1 |   sugar |    
 2017-11-11 |     54.1 |
```

A think, I should write somehow `WHERE mozg.btb_date ‹ ...`

But i do not how to implement this.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes a WHOLE lot, and I wouldn't be shocked if it didn't work with your real dataset, but it should work against your sample:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT
    gs::date, COALESCE(moves,0) as moves, btb_goods 
  FROM generate_series('2017-10-01','2017-11-30',INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS gs 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(btb_menny),0) as moves, btb_goods, btb_date
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY btb_goods, btb_date) AS mozg 
  ON (date(mozg.btb_date) = gs)
)
select
  gs, sum (moves) over (order by gs) as moves,
  max (btb_goods) over (order by gs) as btb_goods
from cte
order by gs
```

That is missing (I **think**) is what do you do when you encounter another record with a non-null value, especially on the text (but also on the number).  How do you want that handled?

In other words, what is the desired result when your initial query returns this:

```
11/1/2017     0
11/2/2017    12     jelly
11/3/2017     0
11/4/2017    15     jam
11/5/2017     0
```

Comment: Thnx, your solution works as i thought it should have been worked, but as you pointed out my initial idea is wrong... I think, i should handle the output by my program instead of reqire it from postgres.

Comment: That's quite possible and a good acknowledgement -- some tasks, while possible, just aren't suited for an RDBMS.  It's why we have multiple tools at our disposal